# Why is Get-MobileDevice not returning the devices based on this filter?

Tags: powershell, exchange-server, exchange-server-2019

I am trying to query Exchange 2019 to return devices based on a users name but the filter I am using is not returning what I expect.

For example my mobile device record contains a UserDisplayName as follows

```
UserDisplayName         : Our.domain/Domain Sites/Corp/Todd D. Welch
```

When I run the bellow command it returns my record as I would expect along with anyone else with the name Todd

```
Get-MobileDevice -filter {UserDisplayName -like '*todd*'}
```

But when I run this more specific query it returns no results

```
Get-MobileDevice -filter {UserDisplayName -like '*todd*welch*'}
```

To me it seems like the above command should return just my device information and I am not seeing why it is not.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I have never found there to be much flexibility with OPath filtering. I think the issue is where you use the asterisks/wildcards. It seems like you can only begin and/or end your search string with a single wildcard. Anything else just finds nothing. I bet you that even `-filter {UserDisplayName -like '*tod**'}` fails. I wish I had a better answer than that. You are likely going to have to do what already works and then filter further with `Where-Object`, which is what nobody wants to hear.

Comment: Even with the Where Object the wildcard does not seem to work as expected.

This finds nothing:

Get-MobileDevice | Where-Object {$_.UserDisplayName -like "*todd welch*"}

This finds all the records with todd in the UserDisplayName just like the -filter does above

Get-MobileDevice | Where-Object {$_.UserDisplayName -like "*todd*"}

Comment: This code does work but man that is convoluted and a waste of processing resources.

Get-MobileDevice -Filter {UserDisplayName -Like "*todd*"} | Where-Object {$_.UserDisplayName -like "*welch*"}

Comment: It is actually better to combine both than to just use `Where-Object` alone. Any calculation and operation piped into `Where-Object` will need to be processed completely before `Where-Object` will process it. `Where-Object` will always be slower than `-filter`. You would need something like `-filter {UserDisplayName -like '*todd*'} | Where-Object {$_.UserDisplayName -like "*welch*"}`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you can chain your criterias as the `Get-MobileDevice` [docu](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/exchange/devices/get-mobiledevice?view=exchange-ps) states:

> You can chain multiple search criteria   together using the logical operators -and and -or. For example, {) -and } or {( -and ) -or }.

So you could try :

```
$str = "Our.domain/Domain Sites/Corp/Todd D. Welch"

($str -like '*todd*') -and ( $str -like '*welch*')
```

Which returns `True` in the [online version](https://tio.run/##K8gvTy0qzkjNyfn/X6W4pEjBVkHJv7RILyU/NzEzT98FTCkEZ5akFus75xcV6Ifkp6QouOgphKfmJGcocXFpgHXp5mRmpyqoa5UAZbXUNRV0E/NSFDQUUOTKQTpAklxc//8DAA) .

Hope that helps.

Comment: I ran this command and it did work finding only my record with the correct first and last name.  Thanks Moerwald!

Get-MobileDevice -Filter {(UserDisplayName -Like "*Todd*") -and (UserDisplayName -Like "*Welch*")}

NOTE: The commenting system is editing out the * before and after each name.